# calculating Distribution function $Z=X+Y$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

suppose $X$ is a random variable with Bernoulli distribution and $P=0/5$ and $Y  $ is Random variable independent of the $X$ with 
Distribution function $F$. how can I calculate Distribution function $Z=X+Y$

Answer (score 1):

You could start with:

$$F_Z(x)=\Pr(X+Y\leq x)=$$$$\Pr(1+Y\leq x\wedge X=1)+\Pr(Y\leq x\wedge X=0)$$
And applying independence.